# Do you know any REST generator for nestjs BE nodejs framework?

Tags: rest, generator, nestjs

I've searched and i've found nothing
I'm trying to find REST generator to generate controller, service, module etc. from model but it's hopeless
Is there are some generator like Gii in Yii2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your are looking for this : https://docs.nestjs.com/cli/usages

For example you can generate an `user` service by using :

```
nest generate service users
```

---

You can also look at this Yeoman generator :
https://github.com/ashinzekene/generator-nestjs-app

> This generator helps you create a NestJS app with ease. It also comes with support for the following :
>
> Decorators, Exceptions, Guards, Interceptors, Middlewares, Modules

---

Or you can try this starter kit :
https://github.com/rcanessa89/nest-js-starter

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely check out this Full-Stack nest-js + Angular generator. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-flare

It is still in its Beta phase but is developing very rapidly. It scaffolds a Nest-js server with Passport authentication and API auth guards pre-configured.
It also has an entity generator. You can create Entities easily using that entity generator.